# Is there any way to intercept Android M Bluetooh off scanning data?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow, eddystone, beacon

I just have read that Android M performs bluetooth scanning even when the bluetooth is off

[image]

(Here is the first question: Is it only BLE scanning?).

So i thought it would be reallly nice to intercept that scanning data to discover the beacons.

I tried to register a broadcast receiver for *android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND* in Manfest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BluetoothReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Unfortunetally that broadcast only comes on Android 5.1 and less but not the M.

Is there any way to intercept that scnanning data in order to save a battery and not running a service that manually performs scans, as the Android Beacon Library from Radius Network does?